# Hiding Category when there are no documents xpages

Tags: xpages

I have an xpage with a categorized view and the first column shows categories that the user may not have access to see the documents underneath them.  So they should be hidden from the view on the web.  I am sure there is an easy way to do this using something like......

```
<xp:viewPanel value="#{view1}" var="rowData" id="viewPanel1" rows="50">
    if (rowData.IsCategory()) {
        if (rowData.(WHATEVER THE PROPERTY IS THAT SHOWS # OF DOCUMENTS FOR THE CATEGORY)) < 1 {
            DON'T SHOW ROW
           }
    }
```

But I can't find the property for # of documents.  Is there one?  If not, then would you use a repeat control to handle empty categories?  If that's the proper way to handle this, can you point me to some code example that would handle this using the repeat control.  It's one of the trickier concepts for me right now.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a setting on the view itself (not the view panel, the actual view design element) to suppress empty categories. If you enable that setting for the view, any view panel bound to it should respect the setting.

Comment: What is this "actual view design element" you speak of LOL.  Thanks for reminding me about this setting.

Comment: you can get into troubles easily: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1LO58079